# regex Java splitting a comma-separated String but ignoring commas within quotes+braces+recursive brackets

Tags: java, regex

I have a string line like this:

```
valueA,{"property1":"value1","property2":"[[[1.5,1.7],[1.9,0.7],.....,[0.5,0.9]]]","property3":"value3",.....,"propertyn":"valueN"},valueB,{"property1":"value1","property2":"[[[1.5,1.7],[1.9,0.7],.....,[0.5,0.9]]]","property3":"value3",.....,"propertyn":"valueN"},valueC,{"property1":"value1","property2":"[[[1.5,1.7],[1.9,0.7],.....,[0.5,0.9]]]","property3":"value3",.....,"propertyn":"valueN"}
```

That I want to split by commas

the above string should split into:

```
valueA
{"property1":"value1","property2":"[[[1.5,1.7],[1.9,0.7],.....,[0.5,0.9]]]","property3":"value3",.....,"propertyn":"valueN"}
valueB
{"property1":"value1","property2":"[[[1.5,1.7],[1.9,0.7],.....,[0.5,0.9]]]","property3":"value3",.....,"propertyn":"valueN"}
valueC
{"property1":"value1","property2":"[[[1.5,1.7],[1.9,0.7],.....,[0.5,0.9]]]","property3":"value3",.....,"propertyn":"valueN"}
```

Try it but It doesn't split well.

```
String[] tokens = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Regex might be the wrong tool for this. Regular expressions are very bad at dealing with any kind of nested brackets/structure.

Comment: Thank you mypetlion for your comment, How to deal with this kind of nested brackets/structure apart from using regEx ? Do you know please any already existing library or technique that could make my life easier? Thank you.

Comment: There are plenty of libraries that let you parse based on actual grammar rules. Just pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of splitting try to extract the data with a pattern matcher.

```java
String line = "valueA,{\"property1\":\"value1\",\"property2\":\"[[[1.5,1.7],[1.9,0.7],.....,[0.5,0.9]]]\",\"property3\":\"value3\"},valueB,{\"property1\":\"value1\",\"property2\":\"[[[1.5,1.7],[1.9,0.7],.....,[0.5,0.9]]]\",\"property3\":\"value3\"},valueC,{\"property1\":\"value1\",\"property2\":\"[[[1.5,1.7],[1.9,0.7],.....,[0.5,0.9]]]\",\"property3\":\"value3\"}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([,]*(value[A-Z])),(\\{\"[\\w\":,\\[\\].]+\"\\})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

while (matcher.find()) {
    String key = matcher.group(2);
    String value = matcher.group(3);

    data.add(key);
    data.add(value);

    System.out.println(key);
    System.out.println(value);
}
String[] array = data.toArray(new String[0]);
```

**Resulting output:**

```
valueA
{"property1":"value1","property2":"[[[1.5,1.7],[1.9,0.7],.....,[0.5,0.9]]]","property3":"value3"}
valueB
{"property1":"value1","property2":"[[[1.5,1.7],[1.9,0.7],.....,[0.5,0.9]]]","property3":"value3"}
valueC
{"property1":"value1","property2":"[[[1.5,1.7],[1.9,0.7],.....,[0.5,0.9]]]","property3":"value3"}
```

Comment: How to wrap the resulting output into an array of  String[] with 6 elements each time ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simpler approach to use split with ",{" as the separator.

```
String[] tokens = line.split(",{");
```

The result would be as follows:

```
tokens[0] = "valueA"
tokens[1] = "property1":"value1","property2":"[[[1.5,1.7],[1.9,0.7],.....,[0.5,0.9]]]","property3":"value3",.....,"propertyn":"valueN"}
```

So the only work left would be to add the starting bracket `{`

Comment: This will only work if there are no instances of `,{` inside of the brackets/quotation marks. Also, you can use positive lookahead to avoid the issue with the missing `{`. So it would be `line.split(",(?={)");`

Comment: @mypetlion you are right, I assumed the values would be more like numeric values.